# How can I shorten code of function scroll?

Tags: javascript

```
for(x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    var board = document.createElement('div');
    board.className = "div";
    document.getElementById('body').insertBefore(board, document.getElementById("body").firstElementChild);
}
window.onscroll = function()
{
    'use strict';
    if(body.scrollTop >= body.children[0].offsetTop)
    {
        body.children[0].style.opacity = ".1"
    };
    if(body.scrollTop >= body.children[1].offsetTop - 100)
    {
        body.children[1].style.opacity = ".1"
    }
};
```

I am looking to a style when `ScrollTop` if `Body` equals `offsetTop` of the div element. I am trying to make this code shorter as I would need 20 of this.

Comment: So why would you need 20 of them? Seems like copy/paste is bad practice in development.

Comment: I want to make the code more smart;

Comment: i know so that i can ask this question to make the code more smart this practice will take 40 line  but i want to do it in for loop

Comment: Don't see any reason why'd you want to make it shorter. If you are concerned with loading times, use a minifier.